# How to restore correct ownership in nspawn containers after upgrade?

Tags: permissions, systemd, upgrade, systemd-nspawn

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. I am running a few containers with `systemd-nspawn`.

After the upgrade, some of the permissions in containers are not mapped correctly:

```
root@delug:/tmp# ls /root
ls: cannot open directory '/root': Permission denied

root@delug:/tmp# ls -l /
total 60
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Nov 22 16:38 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Apr 12  2016 boot
drwxr-xr-x   7 root   root     440 Nov 26 10:23 dev
drwxr-xr-x  82 root   root    4096 Nov 26 10:23 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Apr 12  2016 home
drwxr-xr-x   9 root   root    4096 Jul 23 23:23 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Nov 22 16:38 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Jul 14 14:34 media
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root    4096 Jul 27 21:16 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Oct 13 21:11 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 208 nobody nogroup    0 Nov 26 10:23 proc
drwx------  17 nobody nogroup 4096 Nov 25 20:57 root
drwxr-xr-x  12 root   root     440 Nov 26 10:23 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Nov 22 16:38 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Jul 14 14:34 srv
drwxr-xr-x   9 root   root     180 Nov 26 10:23 sys
drwxr-xr-x   4 nobody nogroup 4096 Nov 20 19:40 temp
drwxrwxrwt   7 root   root     140 Nov 26 10:23 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root   root    4096 Jul 14 14:34 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root   root    4096 Jul 14 14:34 var
```

This also happens when I `debootstrap` a new yakkety image (same problem as above).

**How to restore the correct permissions / ownership mapping?**

---

*Note: I [filed a bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4743) about the behaviour below but hope to fix my existing containers.*